# Looks like Salesforce ETPush SDK is taking a long time on startup

Tags: mobilepush-android

I ran NimbleDroid (to analyze Cold Startup time) on our android app that uses the Salesforce ETPush sdk and it reported the following issue:

Speed - Hot Methods

A hot method takes more than 100ms of total app CPU time to execute all its calls.

```
CPU Time    Method Name

1173 ms     com.exacttarget.etpushsdk.util.AesCbcWithIntegrity.generateKeyFromPassword
```

Here's how we are currently using the SDK:

OurApplication.onCreate():

- Creates an ETPushConfig
- Calls ETPush.configureSdk with a listener

OurMainActivity.onCreate()

- If the user is not logged in (no local token), immediately calls: ETPush.getInstance().setSubscriberKey([Device ID]);
- If the user is logged in, on the getUserInfo callback from our backend calls:
  ETPush.getInstance().setSubscriberKey([UserId]);

Comment: Can you please investigate why this is taking so long and if there is a better way to do it so that it doesn't impact app startup?  Is there a better place to open issues with the SDK?

Comment: The delay is almost certainly caused by the salt being stored in local storage, but this should all be happening in a thread and completely non-impactful to your application as long as you are not making any calls to `ETPush.getInstance()` before the interface has called your implementation of `onETPushConfigurationSuccess()` at which point you are handed an instance of `ETPush` and would not need to call `getInstance()` anyway.

Comment: If you could share how you're starting up the application that would be helpful.

Comment: Added info about what we are calling in the original post - for the scenario that NimbleDroid analyzed - configureSdk would be called in Application.onCreate() and then the getInstance().setSubscriberKey would be called almost immediately after in the Activitiy.onCreate() which I'm guessing might explain the scenario you described.  Sounds like we should change our code to call setSubscriberKey either in onETPushConfigurationSuccess (not logged in or already got user info callback) or afterwards (getUserInfo callback comes in after onETPushConfigurationSuccess has happened)?

Comment: Let me know if this is resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/LearningAppAndroid/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/salesforce/marketingcloud/android/demoapp/MainActivity.java#L111 for an example of how we're delaying those `ETPush.getInstance()` calls to ensure we're not getting blocked.

By doing ^^^ we can make future calls to the Application class to `getPush()` and it will return immediately.

Comment: Thanks.  Just a side note - the example app and SDK documentation both show the following error handling code - which can crash the app due to `e.getMessage()` possibly returning null (which will crash the Log call) - we've seen this in Crashlytics:  `catch (ETException e) { Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage()); }` The fix is either to only log if not null or to concatenate e.getMessage() a with a (blank) string.

Comment: I can't think of an instance where we would return an ETException without a message, but you are correct.  The next time you see one of those shoot me the details and I'll try to find the root cause.  I'll file a documentation bug for ^^^.  Thank you.

Comment: Here's the crashlytics trace:

`Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
       at android.util.Log.println_native(Log.java)
       at android.util.Log.e(Log.java:307)
       at OurApplication$5.onETPushConfigurationFailed(SourceFile:1900)
       at com.exacttarget.etpushsdk.ad.run(SourceFile:460)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)`

Device: SCH-I535 SDK: 4.4.2 ETPush: 4.5.0

Comment: Thank you for providing that.  I will add it to the internal ticket I created for this issue.

Comment: The work to resolve this has been prioritized and will be resolved in an upcoming release.  Thank you again for pointing out this issue.